# Chrome Extension - Manifest v3 - unable to access payload / requestBody using chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener()

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have been asked to create a Chrome Extension that our Business Analysts can use to examine requests to our Analytics service from our website.

These requests are always POSTs. Most of the POSTs include the parameters and values in the query parameters, however some only include them in the payload / requestBody.

I am able to access the query parameters through the URL of the request, but if I attempt to access the requestBody, only { error: "Unknown error" } is returned.

`manifest.json` contains

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Analytics Events Viewer",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": ["storage", "webRequest", "tabs", "background"],
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "devtools_page": "devtools.html"
}
```

`background.js` contains

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  (details) => {
    if (details.url.includes(analyticsHost)) {
      console.log("Captured request:", details);
      capturedData.push(details);
      broadcastData();
    }
  },
  { urls: ["<all_urls>"] },
  ["requestBody"]
);
```

In the logged message:

```json
{
    "documentId": "F26958E0F2FE1389310B8811E829D080",
    "documentLifecycle": "active",
    "frameId": 0,
    "frameType": "outermost_frame",
    "initiator": "https://www.example.com",
    "method": "POST",
    "parentFrameId": -1,
    "requestBody": {
        "error": "Unknown error."
    },
    "requestId": "482447",
    "tabId": 710090930,
    "timeStamp": 1708721967668.82,
    "type": "ping",
    "url": "www.example.com"
}
```

Does anyone know how I can access the payload / requestBody?

Comment: It should be usable as-is, so it must be a bug in Chrome e.g. maybe it doesn't support `"type": "ping"`.